# Formula error ( The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '=' ) in process builder

Tags: process-builder, formula, error

I have this error that keeps returning in my process builder. Not sure what I'm missing. I'd appreciate some help. Looked for too long over it and now I just don't know anymore. Please, help!

```
OR(
        AND(
                  ISNEW(), 
                  OR(
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].BillingStreet )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].BillingPostalCode )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].BillingCity )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].BillingState )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].[Account].BillingCountry )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].Billing_Street2__c)),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].Billing_House_Name__c )),
                         NOT( ISBLANK([Account].Billing_House_Number__c ))  
            
                 )
         ),  
           ISCHANGED( [Account].BillingStreet ), 
           ISCHANGED( [Account].BillingPostalCode ), 
           ISCHANGED( [Account].BillingCity ), 
           ISCHANGED( [Account].BillingState ),
           ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCountry),
           ISCHANGED([Account].Billing_Street2__c),
           ISCHANGED([Account].Billing_House_Name__c ),
           ISCHANGED([Account].Billing_House_Number__c )
          
)
```

Comment: is `NOT( ISBLANK([Account].[Account].BillingCountry )),` a typo, or does that actually exist in your formula?

Comment: That was it! omg...I really need a second pair of eyes. Longest Friday ever...dk how I missed that. Thank you!!